# Find $B $ s.t. $B=\lbrace y\in s \mid \sum x_ky_k \text{ converges for all }x\in A\rbrace$ for $A=l_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

let $A$ be a sunbset of $s$,

and let,

$$B=\left\lbrace y\in s \mid \sum x_ky_k\text{ converges for all }x\in A\right\rbrace$$

Could you please find $B$ if (i) $A=s$ and (ii) $A=l_\infty$

we worked on them for an hour. not much for (i). for (ii) we found the answer $s$th like $l_1 - \text{alternating series}$

it is from the book: Maddox, Elements of Functioanl Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case (i), $A = s$, $B$ consists of the sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms.

It is clear that for a sequence $(y_k)$ where $y_k \neq 0$ for only finitely many $k$, and any sequence $(x_k)$, the sum

$$\sum x_k y_k$$

converges, since it has only finitely many nonzero terms. On the other hand, if $y_k \neq 0$ for infinitely many $k$, then consider

$$x_k = \begin{cases}\:\; 1 &, y_k = 0\\ \dfrac{1}{\lvert y_k\rvert} &, y_k \neq 0.\end{cases}$$

Then $x_ky_k$ does not converge to $0$, and a fortiori $\sum x_ky_k$ does not converge.

In case (ii), $A = l_\infty$, we have $B = l_1$. For if $y \in l_1$ and $x\in l_\infty$, we have

$$\sum \lvert x_k y_k\rvert \leqslant \sum \lVert x\rVert_\infty \lvert y_k\rvert = \lVert x\rVert_\infty \lVert y\rVert_1 < \infty,$$

so the sum is absolutely convergent, and a fortiori convergent.

And if $y \notin l_1$, consider

$$x_k = \begin{cases}\;\: 1 &, y_k = 0\\ \frac{\overline{y_k}}{\lvert y_k\rvert} &, y_k \neq 0. \end{cases}$$

Then $\lvert x_k\rvert = 1$ for all $k$, so $x \in l_\infty$, and for every $k$ we have $x_k y_k = \lvert y_k\rvert$, hence

$$\sum x_k y_k = \sum \lvert y_k\rvert = +\infty.$$